# Debug Secondary Tiles (attaching debugger)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How do you attach the debugger to the Windows Emulator (or Device) to debug runs from Secondary Tiles?

I'm created a secondary tile but it has some problems loading the data and I can quite figure out what is going wrong. How can i attach to the process so i can debug it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. A click on a live-tile doesn't resume the previous instance, but creates a new one (or resets the navigation-stack, from a users perspective it's the same)

But considering that a Live Tile is nothing but a URI, I see no reason you need to click on the actual tile to test the functionality of such a URI. You could simply change the `NavigationPage` property of the `DefaultTask` in the `WMAppManifest.xml`, to be the URI your tile is meant to open with.

If you have a specialized functionality related to your tile, you should tell us, so we can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: yes, make sense as well. Anyway, I already solved the problem, but your comment should be the way to test it.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me...

1. Start app as normal
2. Tap Home
3. Tap second Live Tile

The debugger stays attached when the app closes (this allows testing of tombstoning etc) so it is still attached when you tap the second tile.

Comment: i thought it would work like that, but it is not working for me. as soon as i click the Secondary Tile it opens a new instance and then the debugger disconnects. Any idea how i could fix this without reinstalling anything? Luckely i already debugged the original problem, but i still would love to have this functionality (again).

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind that might be different is that my project has a BackgroundAgent, so that could be keeping my debugger alive longer than yours.

Comment: I also get the debugger to stay attached during the 1-2-3 above. In this project I have a BackgroundAudioAgent. Could the agents be doing it?

Comment: This worked for me. Although simply hardcoding the tileId and flipping your if / switch statement so that the secondary tile action is fired by default also works. however, this method was nice to check that the incoming secondary tileId was picked up correctly and handled. :)